# reconciling multiple forecasts from grouped time series, Hyndman/Athanosopoulos method

Tags: time-series, multilevel-analysis

I am doing grouped forecasting following the [methodology](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/9/4) of Hydman / Athanasopoulos described here:

> ...series can be naturally grouped together based on attributes without necessarily imposing a hierarchical structure. For example the bicycles sold by the warehouse can be for males, females or unisex. They can be used for racing, commuting or recreational purposes. They can be single speed or have multiple gears. Frames can be carbon, aluminum or steel.

According to this method, the forecast for bicycles sold by the warehouse would be different, depending on which group (male vs. female vs. unisex, racing vs. commuting vs. recreational, single speed vs. multiple gears, carbon vs. aluminum vs. steel) is chosen.

What I want and what it seems like one would normally want in this case is not 4 separate forecasts, but rather one single forecast for bicycles sold that reconciles all of the data from the non-hierarchical groups to which the bicycle belongs. Is there a good solution to this?

To make the problem more concrete, I have [posted](https://github.com/mgiangreco/pyaf_demos/blob/master/grouping_demo.ipynb) a notebook that uses the `pyaf` package to produce forecasts for `item1` and `item2`. You can see that `item1` belongs to 2 groups (`group1` and `group2`), and therefore there are two different forecasts for `item1`.

How would one make a forecast for `item1` without choosing between `group1` and `group2`? Simply average the two forecasts together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not understood our method. We forecast all series separately, for every item and every group. Then the forecasts are reconciled, so they all add appropriately. There is only one resulting forecast for each item.

Perhaps we have made it clearer in the 2nd edition (still in draft at http://otexts.org/fpp2/ch-hierarchical.html).